# Iterate over dates in a range in batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to know if there is an elegant/simpler way of iterating over a date range, similar to python, in batch script?

For example, if I want to iterate over dates in range 09/01/2013 to 11/01/2014, is there a better way than just three nested loops?

Comment: Don't use batch script. Use PowerShell.

Comment: As much as I generally hate comments like "use another language" - doing this in batch would be a lot of code and asking for pain and trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Save this as .bat

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
@echo off

cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" %*

exit /b %errorlevel%
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */


var d1 = new Date(2013,09,01);
var d2 =  new Date(2014,11,01);

var m1=d1.getTime();
var m2=d2.getTime();
var iDate;

for (var i=m1;i<m2;i=i+86400000) {
    var iDate=new Date(i);
    WScript.Echo(iDate.toString());

}
```

Without date formatting , but it's not so hard to edit this in the jscript part.